# Azure Api Management deploy Single Api Section with Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-api-management

i am new to terraform and i have this problem.

I know it's possible with terraform to deploy an Azure Api Management Infrastructure, but i wanto to integrate the deploy/management of the api section with a Azure DevOps Pipeline.

Can I create a pipeline in Azure DevOps with terraform for release **only one section** in the Api section without release the other section?

I must manage different section for different application and every application must have a pipeline for release only the relative section.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Since API is just a separate resource you could define `azurerm_api_management` in one repository and in second reference to `azurerm_api_management` via data source

```
data "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "search-api"
  resource_group_name = "search-service"
}
```

and create `azurerm_api_management_api`

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "example" {
  name                = "example-api"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.example.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "Example API"
  path                = "example"
  protocols           = ["https"]

  import {
    content_format = "swagger-link-json"
    content_value  = "http://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net/?format=json"
  }
}
```